# Pentaho: Get System info - get previous month

Tags: datetime, pentaho, kettle, system-information

As the title suggest, I would like to get the previous month using the given month from Get System Info. I used `Get System Info` step to get todays month and year, and from there I would like to get the previous month. This is so it would be dynamic and I can ran this any day and still get the correct filter rather than making a hard coded year and month. Is this possible? If so, how do I do that?

Comment: Got the answer already. Nevemind :)

Comment: best practice is once you find answer then answer below your question so it will useful for others and it will save some other person's effort.

Comment: yep, will post it just been very busy lately. Apologize.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is how I did it. This is the overview

[image]

Here is the calculator:

[image]

And concatenate fields:

[image]

There is still a few loop hole on getting the previous month during January. But, that is how I did it.